# Laravel - cannot load resources from public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have form for uploading images in Laravel 5.3. These images are uploaded into directory (`project_root/public/uploads/images/`). When I turn on the URL `example.com/public/uploads/images/filename.png` (eg) or `example.com/uploads/images/filename.png`, I only get `404 NotFoundHttpException`.

The images, of course, there are. But I cant dump the contents of a public folder over URL.

Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: This path `example.com/uploads/images/filename.png` looks correct. Please make double check for your folders and file names.

Comment: Have you checked the permission of that folder?

Comment: The folders and file names are correct, the permissions are correct too.

Comment: Maybe this is permission issue. "sudo chmod -R 777 public/

Answer (score 0):

The 'correct' way is to use your `Storage` facade and store it in the `storage/public` folder.

This folder is like your public folder, but you can apply all kinds of logic that you don't want to put in your `public` folder.

Without knowing more about how you are 'dumping' the contents of your public folder (with code or just a get request?) or how you are saving your files, i can't tell you what the problem is. It could be you have made a custom .htaccess rule?